# Is there a reason combining SELECT TOP with OPTION (FAST N) would change the execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is an example of a query I looked at recently:

```
SELECT TOP 10 id, name
FROM example_table WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN example_table2 WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON example_table.x = example_table2.id
OPTION (FAST 10)
```

Assuming the rest of this somewhat unusual query stays the same...is there any reason why adding OPTION (FAST N) would cause a query already using TOP to go any faster, or run any differently? If so, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close, as I think that your question has already been asked and answered on dba.stackexchange  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135455/what-does-option-fast-in-select-statement-do

Comment: Technically, it could speed your results, although I doubt that it would in such a simple query. In a somewhat more complex query, though, it could change the process flow so the first N records of joined tables are returned more quickly. I've never compared the query plans of TOP vs FAST queries, though, so I can't claim to know for sure. Only testing will tell.  I'm voting to not close, because the dba question asks how something works generally, whereas this one asks what would happen in a specific case. The general answer may be insufficient to answer the special case.

Comment: @DeanOC that question covers pretty well how `OPTION (FAST N)` affects the execution plan by itself, but it's typically used in a query where you would want to retrieve more than N records -- I'm looking for some understanding of whether it has some impact beyond what TOP would already have.

Answer (score 0):

See first of all `OPTION (FAST N)` retrieve first N rows faster then  the query continues execution and produces its full result set.

Even if you don't mention FAST N hint, Sql Query return first N rows fast where N depend upon query to query and execution plan.

for Example suppose,

```
SELECT  id, name
FROM example_table WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN example_table2 WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON example_table.x = example_table2.id
```

Suppose this query return 8000 rows and first 50 row are return faster

If I mention `Top N` and `OPTION (FAST N)` both in same query and in another window I just mention `TOP N` where N<=50 or N<=100 (roughly)

Then both perform same. Check The XML query plan.

If I Use value of N >=3000 then query with `Top N` and `OPTION (FAST N)` perform poorer than `TOP N` alone.

Though `GUI execution` plan is same ,you can see the difference in `XML query plan`.

I notice that `QueryHash,CompileTime and CompileCPU` were different.`CompileTime` and `CompileCPU`  are higher in query with both `Top N` and `OPTION (FAST N)`

You do similar experiment.